# cannot mount luks-encrypted partition from live usb

Tags: boot, mount, live-usb, encryption, luks

For a while my Ubuntu hasn't been booting anymore as it tells me to update the microcode. I've asked about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002215/how-to-update-microcode-before-boot-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata) but wasn't able to resolve it. I had my hard drive encrypted so I've decided to focus on just saving the data I have on there. This means **I am trying to access a luks-encrypted partition using a live usb** and running into a lot of problem.

1. when I open GParted to look at the partition it tells me

> The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
>   Linux says it is 512 bytes.

so far, I have followed most instructions on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line)

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 myvolume
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda3: 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir /media/my_device
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/myvolume /media/my_device
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg1/root' [229.59 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg1/swap_1' [7.89 GiB] inherit
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgchange -ay
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg1" now active
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/myvolume /media/my_device
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo udisksctl mount -b /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg1-root
Error mounting /dev/dm-1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error mounting /dev/dm-1 at /media/root/6f80dde8-85e9-4e1d-b3be-ea0a9d44f5f1: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/dm-1" "/media/root/6f80dde8-85e9-4e1d-b3be-ea0a9d44f5f1"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg1-root,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

dmesg | tail gives me:

> [   56.866350] wlp2s0: authenticate with cc:ce:1e:d7:2e:9b [
>   56.872017] wlp2s0: send auth to cc:ce:1e:d7:2e:9b (try 1/3) [   56.877483] wlp2s0: authenticated [   56.881185] wlp2s0: associate with cc:ce:1e:d7:2e:9b (try 1/3) [   56.886601] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from
>   cc:ce:1e:d7:2e:9b (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2) [   56.889418] wlp2s0:
>   associated [   56.889452] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link
>   becomes ready [  151.963132] NET: Registered protocol family 38 [ 
>   748.825568] JBD2: journal file too short [  748.825570] EXT4-fs (dm-1): error loading journal

I have also tried this with no success:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sda3
Passphrase: 
Unlocked /dev/sda3 as /dev/dm-0.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/dm-0
Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d0 is not a mountable filesystem.
```

Any advice on how to proceed? What would be the best next step to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

At long last, I've found the solution to this problem as it presented on my System 76 Gazelle: [The Holy Grail Solution](https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2015/11/16/how-to-mount-encrypted-lvm-logical-volume/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1221109)